# OBD2 interfacing with external guages

Tags: instrument

Is there some kind of OBD2 hub that can output to five  gauges at once. I’m looking at installing a 5-pod gauge system on to a 2008 Holden Commodore (Pontiac G8) that has an OBD2 port. And I would rather rig something up via OBD2 that can run the 5 gauges at once rather than hard wiring them all individually.

Comment: Also, real cars have fewer gauges. Truly great ones just have one big red light on the dash for "stop!".

Comment: This appears to be of the form of a "shop for me" question that is universally frowned upon in StackExchange land.  There are many solutions available, but most of them are electronic displays rather than old school steam gauges.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.plxdevices.com/product_cat.php?id=MULT

These guys offer ODB2 gauges. Since some gauges are not transmitted over ODB2, and sometimes ODB2 is just too slow... they also offer the ability to daisy chain in new gauge sensors to the 1 display module (or multiple).

You could also just get a Wifi or Bluetooth ODB2 adapter and run an Android or iPad tablet as your gauges. They also sell products for that.